# Exposing C++ unmanaged code class pointers to C# with C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, wrapper

Apologize for my very basic knowledge of C++/CLI, but it has only been introduced to me recently as a necessity. I am trying to create a wrapper for an unmanaged C++ library using C++/CLI. I have followed [this helpful guide](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/) and can confirm that it (somehow) does the trick. The problem I have is with C++ pointers which expose access to public classes in the unmanaged library. In my CPP library I used them to call the methods from several classes, by having access to a single point-of-entry class. In C# I can't access the methods which should be accessible via these class pointers. I am getting an error stating "the member is inaccessible due to its protection level" and the "->" pointer does not grant access to the *exposed class* members.

Here's what my code looks like:

UnmanagedCode::ClassA

```
...
// some code
...
public:
    void doSomething() { ... };
    ClassB* classB() { return classB.get(); };
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ClassB> classB_ {};
```

C++/CLI wrapper

```
public ref class WrapperClass: public ManagedObject<UnmanagedCode::ClassA>
{
public:
    WrapperClass() : ManagedObject(new UnmanagedCode::ClassA) {}; // template class code in the hyperlink
    ~WrapperClass() {};
    void doSomething() { m_Instance->doSomething(); };
    UnmanagedCode::ClassB* classB() { return m_Instance->classB(); };
};
```

C# program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WrapperClass w = new WrapperClass();
        w.doSomething(); // this works fine
        w.classB(); // here is where I am getting the error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My C# knowledge, is not quite as good as my C++, just as a note.
I dont quite get what you are doing here:

```
UnmanagedCode::ClassB* classB() { return m_Instance->classB(); };
```

This line returns a pointer to a ClassB object, that you retrieve in C#. This would require the ClassB to also be a managed object, as far as i know, otherwise, i dont think you can call functions on the object, without creating delegates for unsafe function pointers.

If i understand your issue correct, i think something like this, would fix your issue, in C++:

```
void* classB() { return static_cast<void*>(m_Instance->classB()); };
void doSomethingWithClassB(void* instance) {static_cast<ClassB*>(instance)->doSomethingWithClassB();}
```

and then in C#:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WrapperClass w = new WrapperClass();
            w.doSomething();
            unsafe
            {
                void* classb = w.classB();
                w.doSomethingWithClassB(classb);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So it seems, that in order to access the members of an unmanaged ClassB I would need to wrap it in C++/CLI separately, correct?

Comment: Yes, i would assume so. You might be able to wrap each function as delegate, however, i only know how to do that with c++ dll's.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide a wrapper for each class to make it useful in c#.

I.e. to return the classB you would write something like

```
MyClassBWrapper^ GetClassB(){ return gcnew MyClassBWrapper(m_Instance->classB());
```

While you can mess around with pointers in managed code, it requires unsafe code, and is quite cumbersome to use. If you are writing a c++/cli wrapper anyway you should provide a fully managed API. With the possible exception of (optionally) using pointers for large data blocks like images or similar.

Comment: The way I access ClassB members in CPP is as follows: classA->classB()->someMethod(). Perhaps the best option for me would be to expose the "someMethod()" directly?

Comment: @szumial that is another possibility. It depends a bit on the design of your API.